# ScriptManager.axd will not cache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

OK, this is driving me crazy.  I've searched for hours & tried almost everything, but scripts downloaded with ScriptManager.axd will not cache.  They ALWAYS end up marked as no-cache with a expires=-1.

I posted this at the following link , but none of that worked.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1728138/4639833.aspx/1?Re+ScriptManager+axd+and+caching

Some things I've tried:

1) Set compilation debug="false" in web.config.

2) Added a HTTP handler that searched for ScriptManager.axd and then set headers.  This is described here: http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/p/34409/34409.aspx.  I actually set a breakpoint in the http handler & confirmed that it was being hit, but guess what?   None of the headers I set for ScriptResource.axd ended up in the response!!!

3) Added this section to web.config.

```
<system.web.extensions >
<scripting >
<scriptResourceHandler enableCompression=“true” enableCaching=“true”/ >
</scripting >
</system.web.extensions >
```

4) set this attribute in machine.config

```
<configuration >
<system.web >
<deployment retail="true" />
</system.web >
</configuration >
```

5) Set ScriptMode="Release"  in the ScriptManager tag.

Seriously, what gives? Why is this so difficult?  Is the ScriptManager that buggy?  Am I missing something obvious?  WHY didn't the response attributes I set in the HTTP handler end up in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Application pool pipeline mode.
Also there may be some Global.asax files in your project which can override the cache header settings.